# Get # of days for week number X

Tags: soql, date

Is there a way to get the total days or hours of each week of a month?

I am using WEEK_IN_MONTH() to get the week number but now I need something like HOURS_IN_WEEK() or DAYS_IN_WEEK() which I can use to generate hours. 
For example, looking at January. 
1st week has 4 days = 96 hours.
2nd week has 7 days =168 hours,
and so on,
Last week has 6 days = 144 hours.

I need this in order to check SLAs for each week of the month.

Comment: A regular week always has 7 days and 168 hours. Do you mean "Business Hours"?

Comment: No, when you pull data by week number you are not going to have the same number of days at the start and end of the month. Example:  [Select SUM(field__c) FROM object__c where WEEK_IN_MONTH(CreatedDate) = 1]. In this scenario the first week of Jan only has  4 days. I need to know that for a formula in the code.

Comment: That is not correct. According to documentation, WEEK_IN_MONTH is "The first week is from the first through the seventh day of the month.". So the first week will always have 7 days. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_date_functions.htm?search_text=WEEK_IN_MONTH

Comment: So the week will not have 7 days only at the end of the month.... But since you know the difference between 28 and the # of days in a month, the calculation should be easy.